# Converting particular columns in dataframe to a numpy array and merging with original data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this

```
Company_id  year  dummy_1 dummy_2 dummy_3 dummy_4 dummy_5
1           1990   1       0        1        1      1
1           1991   0       0        1        1      0
1           1992   0       0        1        1      0
1           1993   1       0        1        1      0
1           1994   0       1        1        1      0
1           1995   0       0        1        1      0
1           1996   0       0        1        1      1
```

I need last 5 columns as a vector and then append it the original dataframe. I know I can slices columns and creata a matrix such as:

```
df.as_matrix(columns=[df[-5:]])
```

Here is the resulting output that I want :

```
 Company_id  year  dummy_1 dummy_2 dummy_3 dummy_4 dummy_5   vector
    1           1990   1       0        1        1      1       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
    1           1991   0       0        1        1      0       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
    1           1992   0       0        1        1      0       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
    1           1993   1       0        1        1      0       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
    1           1994   0       1        1        1      0       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
    1           1995   0       0        1        1      0       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
    1           1996   0       0        1        1      1       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

But then how could I add it as an array to original dataset?

Comment: Sure, adding now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need select last columns by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) new column converted to numpy arrays and lists:

```
df = df.assign(new = df.iloc[:, -5:].values.tolist())
print (df)
   Company_id  year  dummy_1  dummy_2  dummy_3  dummy_4  dummy_5  \
0           1  1990        1        0        1        1        1   
1           1  1991        0        0        1        1        0   
2           1  1992        0        0        1        1        0   
3           1  1993        1        0        1        1        0   
4           1  1994        0        1        1        1        0   
5           1  1995        0        0        1        1        0   
6           1  1996        0        0        1        1        1   

               new  
0  [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]  
1  [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]  
2  [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]  
3  [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]  
4  [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]  
5  [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]  
6  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Sorry, should I say something toarray(), because I will use them for comparsion later on

Comment: @DogukanYılmaz - Then need `df['new'] = df['new'].apply(np.array)` ?